# how to get data using single table inheritance in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

How can I get a record within my single table? I have multiple sub-types while still using single-table inheritance?

```
id | name    |   sex   |   city   |  type   | created_at  |  updated_at
 1 | Akira   | female  |  Jaipur  |  user   | 2014-08-30  | 2014-08-30 
 2 | Nick    |  male   |  Jaipur  |  admin  | 2014-08-30  | 2014-08-30
 3 | Sam     |  male   |  Delhi   |  user   | 2014-08-30  | 2014-08-30
```

this is my single table for user and admin. I want to check the new record before insert. if an old record is user type then not insert again and user type only update record. but an old record is user type then they want to be an admin so I want to insert a new record with admin type.
Like:- Sam is an old user but he want to be an admin so he insert a new record with admin type. but if sam again insert data with user type so I don't want to insert again.

```
id | name    |   sex   |   city   |  type   | created_at  |  updated_at
 1 | Akira   | female  |  Jaipur  |  user   | 2014-08-30  | 2014-08-30 
 2 | Nick    |  male   |  Jaipur  |  admin  | 2014-08-30  | 2014-08-30
 3 | Sam     |  male   |  Delhi   |  user   | 2014-08-30  | 2014-08-30
 4 | Sam     |  male   |  Delhi   |  admin  | 2014-08-30  | 2014-08-30
```

using laravel eloquent relationship

Comment: I'm not clear about if you _want_ to insert another record for the user (which, in my mind, would be a strange design) or if you want to _update_ the existing record with a new type? The most logical solution would be: if a user exists in the database, update the user. If a user don't exist, add the user. Also, "and he want to be admin so he inserts...". Can users set them selves as admin? That's also pretty strange.

Answer (score 1):

```
   $data= $request->first_input_data;
   $isDataExist=ParentProduct::where('name',$data['name'])->where('type','parent')->first();

            if (empty($isDataExist))
            {
                $isDataExist= new ParentData();
            }
            $isDataExist->fill($mainProduct)->save();

            return $isDataExist->id;
```

Same process with child type data another function.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to insert another user on just the same user? I mean, if you want to change the type of user you can just update the type.

But maybe you have reason so maybe in your case you can use `unique` in your `validation`.

```
$this->validate($request,[
       'name' => 'required|string|unique:[nameoftable],name,,,type,'.$request['userType'].'|max:50',
 ]);
```

This will check if the name already exist in the database with the same type you send in your request. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Rule::unique to achieve your validation rule

```
$messages = [
    'data.name.unique' = 'Given name and user type are not unique',
];

Validator::make($data, [
    'data.name' => [
        'required',
        Rule::unique('users')->where(function ($query) use($name,$type) {
            return $query->where('name', $name)
            ->where('type', $type);
        }),
    ],
],
$messages
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Reference this [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html), and add unique key to column `name` in the table.

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD UNIQUE name (name);
```

Now, if you insert same name, you will get a duplicated key error, use raw query:

```
DB::insert(
    'INSERT INTO users (name, sex, city, type) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
     ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE type=VALUES(type)',
    ['Sam', 'male', 'Delhi', 'admin']
);
```

Now, when insert new data and column `name` is duplicated in the table, then update old record column `type`.

By the way, you can use [this package](https://github.com/yadakhov/insert-on-duplicate-key) to alternative raw query.